# Git - chain rebasing issue

Tags: git, rebase

I made 3 branches: each one rebased from the previous one, so it looks like:

`A < B < C < D
 |
master`

Each branch consist of 1 commit that add some feature (method)

**Trouble:** each branch contains previous features, so i can't make pull request with, for example, feature `D`. I need to somehow rebase each of them from master. How? Make temporary branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) has an additional option, `--onto`, which lets you move the root of the branch to a different place. The docs explain this well, but basically, if you rebase `--onto master C D`, it will make a new D' which starts from master, and contains only the changes in D.